# Sort List of Rules in Numeric Order

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have a list of rules,

```
rulelist ={$x1 -> 1, $x10 -> 15, $x11 -> 1, $x2 -> 6, $x3 -> 15, $x4 -> 15, $x5 -> 10, $x6 -> 60, $x7 -> 20, $x8 -> 15, $x9 -> 45}
```

Trying `SortBy[rulelist, Greater]` keeps the rulelist the way it is, and trying `SortBy[rulelist, Last]`
gives

```
{$x1 -> 1, $x11 -> 1, $x2 -> 6, $x5 -> 10, $x10 -> 15, $x3 -> 15, $x4 -> 15, $x8 -> 15, $x7 -> 20, $x9 -> 45, $x6 -> 60}
```

How can I order these rules in numerical instead of canonical order?

Comment: `SortBy[rulelist, Last]`?

Comment: Would an answer that let you replace, say, `$x1` with `$x01` work for you? By renaming the variables in that way, a standard `Sort` would do the job.

Comment: That would work. I'll try that and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a better ordering function in your `SortBy`. Assuming that all your rules look like `$xnnnn` where `n` is a digit, the `ToExpression@StringTake[ToString[#[[1]]], {3, -1}] &` would work.

```
SortBy[rulelist, ToExpression@StringTake[ToString[#[[1]]], {3, -1}] &]
(* {$x1 -> 1, $x2 -> 6, $x3 -> 15, $x4 -> 15, $x5 -> 10, $x6 -> 
  60, $x7 -> 20, $x8 -> 15, $x9 -> 45, $x10 -> 15, $x11 -> 1} *)
```

That's very straightforward way, a more elegant way probably exists.

Brief explanation:

`#[[1]]` takes left side of your rule (you can replace it with `First[#]`)

`ToString` makes a string from the expression

`StringTake[   ,{3,-1}]` takes all characters except first two (removes "$x")

`ToExpression` makes a number out of string, this number is used to order by.

Comment: That's perfect! I'll definitely look at the documentation and see why this works too. Thank you!

Comment: @BJParks I added some explanation. Consider upvoting/accepting the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks again for your help; the explanation is greatly appreciated!