# Adding up a list of rules

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, counting

Here's the problem: I take a count of a count, so that I end up with a list in this format:

```
Table[Counts@Counts@Join[dKm[[i]], Pick[data1, ccKMedoid, i]], {i, 5}]
```

Result:

```
{<|1 -> 76, 2 -> 2|>, <|2 -> 23, 1 -> 32|>, <|2 -> 48, 1 -> 4|>, <|2 -> 50, 1 -> 2|>, <|2 -> 50, 1 -> 42|>}
```

Now what I would like to do is add each element of this list, so I could get a final total of the counts of 2s and 1s. At first I thought what I should do was sort the list of rules by numeric order, so that it was in the format

```
{<|1 -> 76, 2 -> 2|>, <|1 -> 32, 2 -> 23|>, <|1 -> 4, 2 -> 48|>, <|1 -> 2, 2 -> 50|>, <|1 -> 42, 2 -> 50|>}
```

and tried implementing the code here: [Sort List of Rules in Numeric Order](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157071/sort-list-of-rules-in-numeric-order) to do so, by doing something like:

```
SortBy[Table[Counts@Counts@Join[dKmn[[i]], Pick[data1, ccKMean, i]], {i, 5}], First[#]]
```

but that didn't work. Any advice on how to organize the list so I can use Total[] on it, or a smarter way to go about adding up the counts, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
assoc = {<|1 -> 76, 2 -> 2|>, <|2 -> 23, 1 -> 32|>, <|2 -> 48, 
    1 -> 4|>, <|2 -> 50, 1 -> 2|>, <|2 -> 50, 1 -> 42|>};

assoc // Merge[Total]

(* <|1 -> 156, 2 -> 173|> *)
```

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot.